# SSMS Crash when I try to modify the database diagram(v18.5)

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server Management Studio still crashes when I try to modify the Database Diagram. There is no error message. Some of the sites I have looked up are listed below. Some of the solutions I have tried are:

Rebooting SQL Server after it crashed. Didn't worked

Moving SQL Server from my external hard drive to my C: Drive which didn't work as I couldn't rewire the Data path and I am not sure it will fix the problem.

My Visual studio version is 15.9.22 2017.

Has anyone else come across this problem and has fixed it?

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6823b012-f438-405d-a68d-e1a5a8235bbd/microsoft-sql-server-management-studio-still-crashing-when-opening-a-database-diagram?forum=sqlkjmanageability
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035/suggestions/37992649#{toggle_previous_statuses}

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have experienced this problem too. I just had to delete the diagram and create it again that's the only way I found the diagram just wouldn't work anymore. You'll have to create it again I guess.

Comment: No I didn't I took a screenshot (of the diagram) because I knew this problem would occur again.

Comment: Did you figure out the source of the problem? If I recreate the diagram is there a chance of the same thing happening again?

Comment: Yes there is a chance of that happening again.I don't know how to fix all I know is that you have to create it again in order for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I run ver. 18.5.1.
I deleted old diagrams.
Created new.
Rename it or give it other name than default.
It works for now.
:)